# Spring Transaction with AspectJ

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, transactional

I'm having a problem with @Transaction in Spring.
Basically, no transaction is created with the following message:

delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress

I posetd a full description of the problen in the Spring AOP forum

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?132612-Transaction-management

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Stefano

Comment: Could you please post the complete stacktrace. - Mainly to make sure that we search at the right place. Because the code looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have defined the service like this:

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class ServiceImpl<T> implements Service<T> {
@Override
@Transactional
public T save(T entity) {
          ....
    }
}
```

I do not know why you use the `@Configurable` annotation. If you do not need them (*that is if you do not create an instance of this service via new*) , I would remove them.

*The reason is that I remember that spring docu say that `@Configurable` enable injection, but it does not say anything about load time weaving support enabled by `@Configurable`*

Comment: You are correct about `@Configurable` while the `@Service` annotation is a specialization of `@Component`. However the transactional aspect should weaved because of the `@Transactional` annotation at method level, as the docu states.

Comment: I forgot... I tried your suggestion but the resut did not change.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The problem was in the configuratoin. I added two elements `context:spring-configured` and `context:load-time-weaver` that mean two different things. The first one activate AspectJ **compile time** weaving (which I didn't understand), the second one activate AspectJ **load time weaving**. I think that these two elements don't work well together.

I decided to use compile time weaver and (after struggling a little bit...) I found that (obviously) external jars are not weaved with this configuration, simply because they have yet been built.

The easiest way to solve is to modify the configuration of the `aspectj-maven-plugin` (in POM.xml) adding under the `configuration` node:

```
<weaveDependencies>
<weaveDependency>
<groupId>GROUP-ID</groupId>
<artifactId>ARTIFACT-ID</artifactId>
</weaveDependency>
</weaveDependencies>
```

for every artifact you need to weave.

Now transactions work fine!

@Ralph: many thanks for your time!

Regards,

Stefano